# How can some number of seconds be added to a datetime stamp in Bash?

Tags: bash, datetime

Let's say I have a string datetime stamp made in the following way:

```
datetimestamp="$(date "+%Y-%m-%dT%H%MZ" --utc)"
```

How could I easily add some number of seconds to this and print the result in the same form? Let's say I want to add two months (5184000 seconds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very straight simple:

```
date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H%MZ' --utc --date 'now +5184000 seconds'
```

Lets test this:

```
date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H%MZ' --utc; date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H%MZ' --utc --date 'now +5184000 seconds'
```

Output:

```
2019-07-04T0036Z
2019-09-02T0036Z
```

Or just this:

```
date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H%MZ' --utc --date 'now +2 month'
```

Expanding on your question's sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sec_offset=5184000
datetimestamp="$(\
  date \
    '+%Y-%m-%dT%H%MZ' \
    --utc \
    --date "now + ${sec_offset} seconds"
)"
```

Comment: Ah excellent stuff, thank you so much! :D Clear explanation too.